# Substracting MINUTE from Calender not working correctly

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have to set an alarm using `AlarmManager`, before that i need to subtract 10 minutes from the given time. But the output is wrong. it shows more than 10 minute difference in the output. 
My current code look like this

```
 AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Log.e("here value of time",time);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");
        try {
            calendar1.setTime(dateFormatter.parse(time));
            calendar1.set(calendar1.MINUTE,-10);


            Log.e("alarm Set for", String.valueOf(calendar1.getTime()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and i am getting the Log like this

> here value of time: 11-19-2019 1:30 a.m.
>
> alarm Set for: Tue Nov 19 00:50:00 GMT+05:30 2019

Comment: You want to use the `add()` method, not `set()`.

Comment: thanks man. you just saved my day!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

> calendar1.set(calendar1.MINUTE,-10);

to

> calendar1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -10);

Comment: the issue is solved after changing to calendar1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -10);

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding `-10` to the current minutes, you are setting the minutes to a value of `-10` which rolls back the time! Change

```
calendar1.set(calendar1.MINUTE,-10);
```

to

```
calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - 10);
```